# Items disappear when I click in an empty area

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an item search system. But when I find the item(s) I want and click in an empty area, the item(s) disappear. What is the error?

[image]

```
    return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Obx(
      () => Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 15, 15),
        appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            toolbarHeight: 90,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            title: TextField(
              controller: findPressureController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              onChanged: (value) {
                List newList = [];

                if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                  for (var element in pressures) {
                    if (element.pressure.contains(value) ||
                        element.date.toString().contains(value)) {
                      newList.add(element);
                    }
                  }
                  items.value = newList;
                } else {
                  items.value = pressures;
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Search pressure or date...',
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 2.0,
                          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 99, 99, 99)
                              .withOpacity(0.4))),
                  focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 2.0,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 99, 99, 99)))),
              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            )),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return pressureItem(index);
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What is `items`? And what does this GestureDetector do with the Focus?

Comment: @nvoigt, GestureDetector is needed only so that you can close the keyboard by clicking on any empty space. Items is a list of classes in which what you see on the GIF: pressure, date, etc.